# How to create height responsive image in div with static height and some text in it?

Tags: css

I want to have static height slider with info on the right (but it's not important at all).

I've done it, but the main problem is, that if you put some text in the info div content and add image on the end, then I can have responsive width, but I can't have responsive height. Consequently, the entire image isn't visible.

There's an example: http://mkzarka.pl

[image: width higher than 1150px]

Like you maybe saw already, at some point some part of image is hiding, if I have width smaller than 1151px.

[image: width smaller than 1151px]

I want to automatically changing height to smaller, if it's required to see entire image.

Edit:

Forgot to add code:

```
<div id="sliderimg" style="height:400px">
    <div class="module module-slideshow">
        <div class="module-content camera_wrap" style="display: block; height: 400px;">
            some script for slideshow
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module module-custom_html">
        <h2 class="module-title">Letnie kursy żeglarskie dla dzieci</h2>
        <div class="module-content">
            <p>Można już rejestrować dzieci na obozy:</p>

            <p><a href="http://mkzarka.pl/Dostepne-obozy/Letnie-kursy-zeglarskie-dla-dzieci-termin-1">24.07-30.07</a></p>

            <p><a href="http://mkzarka.pl/Dostepne-obozy/Letnie-kursy-zeglarskie-dla-dzieci-termin-2">31.07-06.08</a></p>

            <p><img alt="" src="/p/modules/16/4_319x240.jpg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#sliderimg.module-slideshow{
    width:75%;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#sliderimg.module-custom_html{
    width:25%;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
```

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry forgot about it, added by edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand, You want your image height has mobile height maximum.

If this is you can add this styles to the responsive image:

```
img.responsive{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, your wrapper div is my right div or entire div with left and right sides?

Comment: could you explain more? I know the problem is not hard but maybe i cant find what you want.

Comment: I added one more image to my question. I want some changes about div.module-custom_html.

I have some text in it and image on the end of it. I want to change it height to remaining space, because text is taking some space too.